# CoreData - managedObjectContext:save: is keeping items in the registeredObjects set

Tags: xcode, core-data, memory-management, nsmanagedobject, retain

I think I am missing a crucial part of knowledge when it comes to CoreData and was wondering if someone could help me out. I am trying to create new object entities but my memory is never released after the save. I have an object called UserEntity which contains 2 strings, sUsername and sPassword which are set from UITextFields (see below)

```
+ (BOOL)createUserEntityWithUsername:(NSString *)sUsername andPassword:(NSString *)sPassword
{
    NSArray *user = [self fetchEntitysWithEntityName:@"UserEntity" withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(sUsername = %@)", sUsername]];

    if ([user count] == 0)
    {
        // NSLog (@"User created");

        UserEntity * newEntry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UserEntity"
                                                              inManagedObjectContext:[Singleton sharedSingleton].managedObjectContext];
        //  Setup Params
        newEntry.sUsername = sUsername;
        newEntry.sPassword = sPassword;

        [[Singleton sharedSingleton] saveContext];
        user = nil;

        return YES;
    }

    user = nil;

    // NSLog (@"User found");
    return NO;
}
```

This is called from my view controller as follows:

```
if ([Singleton createUserEntityWithUsername:self.tfUsername.text andPassword:self.tfPassword.text])
    {
}
```

and the saveContext looks like this:

```
   - (void)saveContext
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
        if (managedObjectContext != nil) {        
            if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
               NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Save successful");
            }
        }
        managedObjectContext = nil;
    }
```

This all saves fine, however, if I break after the Singleton create... function then I can see the following:

```
po [[Singleton sharedSingleton].managedObjectContext registeredObjects]
{(
    <UserEntity: 0xa3a4dd0> (entity: UserEntity; id: 0xa3b41d0 <x-coredata://8F241F56-D1A2-4BC2-A575-FF9972B15629/UserEntity/p1> ; data: {
    sPassword = ejd;
    sUsername = ejd2;
})
)}
```

I was under the impression that the NSManagedObjectContext cleared this set after the objects changes have been saved? This is the only NSManagedObjectContext etc, so can anyone explain what's going on as I can't figure out if I'm meant to be explicitly releasing the items in this list, or my memory management is going wrong.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `-reset` on your MOC. And make sure that any references to NSMO's that live in that MOC are invalidated, too.

BTW, don't store passwords in Core Data. They're saved unencrypted, and anyone can read them. Use the Keychain instead.

Comment: Ah okay, so I have to manually do a reset on the MOC everytime I save? Thanks for the info. I've been setting all the references to nil after I've used them etc, I think it's simply the MOC keeping the reference that is making the memory on my app constantly increase. 

Thanks for the info, will switch out the PW's. They aren't actually needed there it was just some dummy data. Will give it a try and get back to you!

Comment: You only need the `reset` if you want the objects freed. If you're going to keep working with them, then don't worry about managing them.